# Angular: Show spinner on button click

Tags: angular

I want to achieve a result of showing spinner when a button is clicked for saving data. The button should hide (in the process of saving the data to back end ) and should then be shown again when data is saved.

Below is HTML code

```
 <div class="card-footer">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col text-danger col-form-label font-weight-bold">(*) Required fields</div>
          <div class="col text-right" *ngIf="!hidebutton">
            <app-spinner *ngIf="!showspinner"></app-spinner>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">To accept</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary ml-4" (click)="getBack()">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**Component.ts code**

```
 export class DocumentFormComponent implements OnInit {
   hidebutton: boolean = false;
  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
  this.hidebutton = true;
const swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
  customClass: {
    confirmButton: 'btn btn-primary',
    cancelButton: 'btn btn-outline-secondary ml-4'
  },
  buttonsStyling: false
});

// validate the form
this.validateForm(form);

// this check if it's a new document to create
if (this.validForm) {
  const newDocument =  this.myDocument;
  const  formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('document', JSON.stringify(newDocument));
  formData.append('attachedFile', this.selectedFile);

  swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: 'You will not be able to revert this!',
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, save it!',
    cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!'
  }).then((result) => {
    // Save Doc
    if (result.value && !this.editing) {
      this.showspinner = true;
      this.documentService.saveDocument(this.customerId, formData)
        .subscribe(respondData => {
            swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
              'Saved!',
              'Your Document has been saved.',
              'success');
            // after success coming back document list
          this.hidebutton = false;
            this.showspinner = false;
            this.router.navigate(['/customers/', this.customerId, 'documents']);
        }, error => {
          swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
            'Didn`t save!',
            'Your Document could`t be saved.',
            'error');
      });}}
```

Comment: So what is the problem you actually face?

Comment: With the above snippets, the spinner shows alongside the button even before the user clicks. When the alert pops to save the file everything hides. The spinner should be running in the background of the popup in the col text-right class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="card-footer">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col text-danger col-form-label font-weight-bold">(*) Required fields</div>
          <div class="col text-right">
            <app-spinner *ngIf="hidebutton"></app-spinner>
            <button *ngIf="!hidebutton" class="btn btn-primary">To accept</button>
            <button *ngIf="!hidebutton" class="btn btn-outline-secondary ml-4" (click)="getBack()">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

try this

Answer (score 2):

Use the save button to toggle your spinner.

```
this.showspinner = this.hidebutton ? this.hidebutton : !this.hidebutton;
```